# gunicron fail to start at specified port

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I tried to make my flask program listens to the port 5000, here is the main part from `app/app.py`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    app.logger.info("Receiving a request")
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        query = request.args.get("query")
        file = request.files['file']
        app.logger.info(query)
        filePath  = '/tmp/tmpDoc'
        # write something to file
        searchResult = bootLoader.run(filePath, query)
        ans = searchResult['answers']
        return jsonify(ans)
    return "hihi"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

and my `wsgi.py`

```
from app.app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

I run the program with gunicorn by `gunicorn wsgi:app`, but neither the debug feature nor the specified port is working. Here are the logs:

```
[2021-02-09 16:50:58 +0800] [62555] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-02-09 16:50:58 +0800] [62555] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (62555)
[2021-02-09 16:50:58 +0800] [62555] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-02-09 16:50:58 +0800] [62558] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 62558
```

Comment: try using `bind`. so your command will be `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app`

Comment: @neilharia7 Yes I have to run the program as `gunicorn --log-level=DEBUG -b 127.0.0.1:5000 wsgi:app`. But isn't the `app.run(...)` in `wsgi.py` is enough to configure that?

Comment: If the bind command is not specified, gunicorn defaults to port `8000`. As per the docs gunicorn has its own config file from where it picks the port.
You can check by running `gunicorn --check-config`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `if __name__ == "__main__":` is never satisfied.

You can run `python app/app.py` what will use built-in WSGI development server.
The same thing will happen after running `python wsgi.py`.

Gunicorn command is not triggering `if __name__ == "__main__":`. You can think about it as gunicorn would import `app` object and run it on it's own. That's why different port number is used. See that if you delete `if __name__ == ...` in both files, guncorn will still be able to run server on port 8000.

Instead you should pass host and port number in gunicorn command with [--bind](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html?highlight=bind#bind).

```
gunicorn wsgi:app -b :5000
```